# swipe event for many list items in jquery

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, jquery

In my Phonegap Android application, I have a list of items for which I have swipe event for each item in the list. I have assigned a unique id for each item of the list but how to get the id of swiped item using Jquery. Below is the code that I have written.

```
for (var i = 0; i < (TotalNoOfCity); i++)
{
        $('#CityList').append('<a href="CityList.html" id="swipe' + ListOfCities[i][0] + '" onclick="CityID=' + ListOfCities[i][0] + ';CityName=' + '\'' + ListOfCities[i][1] + '\';">\
            <div class="listbox">\
                    <div class="listboxtext">' + ListOfCities[i][1] + '</div>\
                    <div class="listboxIcon" class="ui-btn-right" class="ui-btn-right">\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="clear"></div>\
            </div>\
            </a>\
            <div class="clear"></div>');
$('#swipe'+ ListOfCities[i][0]).live('swiperight', function() {

});
```

Comment: In your handler function that is called when a swipe event is fired, $(this) represent the jQuery object embedding your element. Moreover, you have forgot to put the swipeEvent as parameter of your handler function (it could be useful depend on what you're doing).

Comment: Hey user1073122, thank you so much.. I did this.id and got the id of the swiped item that is enough for now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler function that is called when a swipe event is fired, $(this) represent the jQuery object embedding your element. Moreover, you have forgot to put the swipeEvent as parameter of your handler function (it could be useful depend on what you're doing).